# Adjectives ending in -ed and -ing

Tags: adjectives

After adjective ending in -ed like amazed, disgusted what preposition I have to put after? 
For example: I am bored OF/BY the maths test/my friend Luca. 
Are there any rules for this construction?

Answer (score 6):

There are no rules. Learn each expression in examples to help you remember the preposition. (bored with/by, interested in, etc.)

There is an explanation, however, for adjectives ending in -ed and -ing, as mentioned in the title of the post. An adjective ending in -ing describes what the noun is, so the lecture is boring,interesting, etc. An adjective ending in -ed is how you feel, so you feel bored with/by the lecture, or you're interested in the lecture, etc., but there are, of course, other suffixes for adjectives, such as -able, -ible,-ful, -ic, -ive, -less, and -ous, that may describe what something is, or how you feel. Examples help to learn these adjectives, and there are exceptions to almost every rule.

Comment: @VarunKN Hmm, how does this not answer the question? She asked "are there any rules?" and he said "no, there aren't". The answer may be wrong, but it's a direct answer.

Comment: @VarunKN Unhappily, the answer is not only to the point but entirely correct.

Answer (score 1):

As said, no rules. It's just vocabulary.
Common prepositions are *about, with* & *of*. Some examples include:

> 1. confused/guilty/depressed/relieved/angry **about**.
> 2. pleased/fed up/satisfied/irritated/bored **with**.
> 3. jealous/proud/afraid/ashamed/scared **of**.

The problem is that the preposition is fixed, so if you try to use another one, it won't work, specially when doing a test.

Comment: Yes, but *bored of* is just as idiomatic, depending on the context.

Comment: I can be [pleased by](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22pleased+by%22), [bored of](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22bored+of%22), [depressed over](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22depressed+over%22) et. al. The preposition isn't fixed - there's actually quite a bit of variation colloquially.

Comment: @ColleenV Interesting, but are they gramatically correct?

Comment: Yes, they're grammatical, but then again there are plenty of grammatical sentences that are completely meaningless. If you say "I'm bored of you and your comments" I will understand your meaning just as well as "bored with you" and I wouldn't even think to argue with you about your choice of preposition :)

Comment: @ColleenV Nice, the thing is that tests are very strict, so I mostly stick to the rules.

Comment: But there are no rules to stick to for this situation, that's my entire point. The prepositions aren't fixed unless you're taking a test written by a particular teacher who has given you some arbitrary rules to follow to make the test easier. I can imagine contexts where some of the prepositions you've listed would be the wrong choice. I was confused by your note is different from I was confused about your note.